# Future warning message

Tags: python, seaborn

**How can I do to get rid of this warning?**

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn_decorators.py:36: FutureWarning: Pass the following variable as a keyword arg: x. From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument will be `data`, and passing other arguments without an explicit keyword will result in an error or misinterpretation.
warnings.warn([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2NVM.png)

```
sns.countplot(ex_emp['dept'])    
plt.title('Department of Employees Who Left')    
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))    
plt.savefig('ex_dept.png', bbox_inches='tight')    
plt.show()
```

Comment: The warning tells that in a future seaborn version you will need to write `sns.countplot(x=ex_emp['dept'])`. You are encouraged to already do it that way now. Without the proper keyword it can quickly get confusing which plot is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the warning is just indicating that usage of positional arguments (except `data`) is going to be disallowed in future `seaborn` versions. The code is working right now, but, besides removing the warning, by adjusting it you can ensure it will continue working when `seaborn` is upgraded.

According with [the `sns.countplot()` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) (and with the warning message itself), the argument you should pass by keyword is `x`. The following line needs to be adjusted:

```py
sns.countplot(ex_emp['dept'])
```

If I'm not misinterpreting the documentation, both of the following replacements should work:

```py
# 1st option
sns.countplot(x=ex_emp['dept'])

# 2nd option
sns.countplot(ex_emp, x='dept')
```

Just in case, give them a try!